# Сообщение "Stack overflow" (исключение EStackOverflow)

Tags: delphi

Добрый день! Подскажите пожалуйста, когда может появляться сообщение "Stack overflow" (исключение EStackOverflow)? 
Стало появляться после того, как написал обработчик события AfterScroll для ADODataSet:

```
with DataModule1.UmzDpd do
begin
if Active=True then
begin
  First;
  while Eof<>True do
  begin
    Edit;
    if FieldByName('НаличиеРСТ').AsBoolean=True then
      FieldByName('НаличРСТ').AsString:= 'Да'
    else
      FieldByName('НаличРСТ').AsString:= 'Нет';
    Next;
  end;
  First;
end;
end;
```

Здесь присваивается значение вычисляемому полю (оно исчезает в гриде всякий раз, как переходишь на другую строку). В чем может быть ошибка?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Почти всегда причина - бесконечная рекурсия. Видимо в результате действий вашего обработчика снова вызывается `AfterScroll`.

Comment: Вот спасибо, это очень похоже на правду!

Answer (score 4):

Срабатывает обработчик, в нем вызывается `Next`, это вызывает срабатывание обработчика... и так до бесконечности, пока не забивается стек.

Как костыль - можно завести булеву переменную для блокировки обработчика: в начале обработчика проверять флаг, если его значение `false` - выставлять в `true` и выполнять остальную часть, в противном случае (если `true`) - выходить. Тогда при попытке повторно зайти в обработчик его выполнение тут же прекратится. Переменная должна быть объявлена не в самом обработчике, а выше (в модуле, в классе).

Другой костыль - в начале обработчика, выставлять вашему набору данных `AfterScroll := nil`, а в конце - возвращать обратно `AfterScroll := ...`.

В обоих вариантах код обработчика стоит завернуть в `try-finally` и разблокировку выполнять в блоке `finally`. В противном случае, при возникновении исключения, вы останетесь без обработчика.

А вообще лучше разобраться, что у вас там с вычисляемым полем.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Nofate, а как обратно присвоить AfterScroll := .... ? Что писать, где многоточие?

Comment: AfterScroll := @ИмяФункцииОбработчика;

Comment: С собакой не работает, работает, если просто AfterScroll:=ИмяФункцииОбработчика; Спасибо.

Answer (score -1):

Что касается циклической обработки попробуйте.

```
if Active then begin
  DisableControls;
  ....
  EnableControls;
end;
```

В остальном лучше все обернуть в try except и загнать в транзакцию. При таком подходе данные в базе гарантировано будут сохранены правильно или не сохранены вовсе.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!